# Script to rotate an image and switch image halfway through animation

Tags: javascript, css, image, rotation, transition

I am writing a script to rotate an image in the Y direction on hover, and switch the image to a different one at the 90 degrees point (the intended effect is that when the image is hovered, it flips round to show the "back" side).

My javascript is as follows:

```
$('.designthumb').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    var x = this;
    var img = $(this).attr('src');
    var path1 = img.split('.png');
        $(x).css('-webkit-transform','rotateY(90deg)');
        $(x).css('transform','rotateY(90deg)');
        $(x).on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', 
            function(e) {
                if (path1[0].substr(path1[0].length - 4) == 'back') {var newpath = path1[0]+'.png';}
                else {var newpath = path1[0]+'back.png';}
                $(x).attr('src',newpath);
                $(x).css('-webkit-transform','');
                $(x).css('transform','');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        $(x).on('mouseout', function(e) {
            $(x).css('-webkit-transform','rotateY(90deg)');
            $(x).css('transform','rotateY(90deg)');
                $(x).on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', 
                function(e) {
                    if (img.split('.png')[0].substr(img.split('.png')[0] - 4) == 'back') {var imgo = img.split('back')[0]+'.png';}
                    else {var imgo = img.split('.png')[0]+'.png';}
                    $(x).attr('src',imgo);
                    $(x).css('-webkit-transform','');
                    $(x).css('transform','');
                });
            });
});
```

I have created a fiddle, but, somehow, I am just fiddle-tarded and my fiddles never work properly, or in this case at all. Nonetheless you can view my somewhat simplified attempt here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xenthide/u6nauzqg/

The above code **SORT OF** works, the HTML is fairly trivial so I won't bother posting it, basically I have a selection of images classed as `designthumb`, with names such as image1.png, image2.png, with corresponding files image1back.png image2back.png, etc. The intended effect is that the user can hover over an image and see the back image.

However, it only really works if the user firmly moves the mouse onto the image, then stops moving it entirely. Otherwise the transition wobbles around, doesn't complete, and is just buggy as fuck. I'm not sure if that current version is still doing it but previous attempts of mine have somehow managed to get stuck on the back image even when the cursor is moved away from it. The possibly odd looking if/else statements are my efforts to prevent that.

Really I would like some way to FORCE the transition to complete, smoothly, as soon as the cursor touches that region, without the current annoying wobbly crap going on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without javascript: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u6nauzqg/1/)**

```
.design {
    background:url(http://www.graphicsfuel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/emoticon-sad.png) center no-repeat;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-size:0 100%;
    padding:0;
    height:374px;
    width:326px;
}
.design:hover {
    width:0;
    padding:0 163px ;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

---

here some more ideas with effects using same method : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Joqzp 
and a flip effect **very close** to what you try to do : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/cHirI

Comment: That second Pen shudders badly when I tried it and the mouse is in a position where the image rotates away from under the pointer.

Comment: @thisiate i guess it needs some tunning on how fast, how much you want to shrink: a) image (width/height) and  b) background (background-size). Timing can be tune via animation(with a scenario/tile line) instead simple transition taking all together. This is a method, do whatever you like with it